# How to adjust operator settings after leaving the settings panel

Tags: interface

I've added a torus knot using the the "Add Curve: Extra Objects" addon. I've done some work on the scene, and now would like to go back change the knot parameters that were in the operator settings when I first added the curve.

How do I get back to that panel to adjust operator settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Once you perform another operation, the changes are set.

However, the operator should retain its last-used settings; you can delete the knot and re-add it, then change the settings to suit your liking.

If you want to change the settings before doing anything else, you can use the panel in the Tool Shelf, or press <kbd>F6</kbd> in the 3D View to bring up the options for the last-used operator.

Comment: Is this general for all "add this special object" addons? Is it possible for an object to remember that it originated from an addon, in order to stay flexible to constructor parameters, if the addon was written with enough care?

Comment: This is the default behavior. I suppose it would be possible for an operator to write custom properties to the object or mesh datablock, and then have a "refresh" button or hook. However, I don't know of any addons that would do this.

Comment: Does that mean that if I add a tree with the "sapling" add-on, put in a lot of work to format it, and then later on, when I want to change something to the tree, I can't, unless I start all over again? It's all very well that the operator remembers its last settings, but what if I have ten trees, and want to re-edit the third. The operator then only has remembered the tenth (= last) tree ...

Comment: @TavernSenses Unfortunately, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the current behaviour for Blender nor the current crop of addons. There is a development proposals for [editable object parameters](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Source/Development/Proposals/Editable_Object_Parameters) on the wiki. I also seems to remember talk of a editable history stack like [gSculpt](http://gsculpt.sourceforge.net/) in one of the Blender conference videos (but perhaps the current redo last step is all that was planed, *I don't know*).

I the mean time, a lot of primitives can be parameterised using [modifiers](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers).

For you torus knot the *Surface* setting when creating the torus are just the standard properties found under [Object data](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Curves#Curve_Properties).

Answer (score 0):

Like @Aldrik said it is impossible by default in Blender, maybe in the future it will be changed. Anyway I can suggest you an addon where such things are possible.
It's called [ArchitectureLab](https://github.com/insma/ArchitectureLab) and available on GitHub. I have the same problem and decided to develop a plugin to make it possible modify object properties at any time in Blender. If you will require additional feature just make a request on the GitHub issues page.