# What to do when I get the message "subsurf modifier need to be first to work with unwrap"?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I am trying to *UV unwrap* an object. However, I keep getting the following messsage when I try to unwrap:

> subsurf modifier need to be first to work with unwrap

I have tried adding *subsurf modifier*, but I keep getting this message. What can I do in this situation?

[image]

Comment: I didn't get those messages especially on the object with Subsurf, however that message means option of unwrapping checked which assumes using Subsurf.

Comment: Try looking in the Last Operator panel on the Toolshelf (or `F6`) if *Use Subsurf Modifier* is checked. It could be enabled accidentally, although it should go away as long as Subsurf is present.

Answer (score 1):

That message tells you that while [unwrapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#unwrap) you enabled option *Use Subsurf Modifier*. It lets you avoid applying Subsurf modifier if you have it in the stack while having vertices in the UV map moved as if the modifier was applied.
Note: it doesn't mean all the geometry which will be added with Subsurf will appear on the map with this option; it only allows existing vertices to be moved as close to "subsurfed" positions as possible.

However in order this to work as expected Subsurf modifier has to be the first in the stack, otherwise this message will pop up everytime you unwrap the mesh with that option enabled.
If you unwrapped once and accidentally enabled the option [these settings will be saved](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2296/33624) and then every time you unwrap you will see the mentioned message if Subsurf isn't present. Just disable it if not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Under your modifiers panel how many modifiers are you using? More than 1 I assume. What that message means is that for that to work you have to put the subsurf modifier in the top of all your modifiers, then it will work. Whether is the outcome what you expect, fine, if not you will have to try you unwrap in a different way (maybe applying the subsurf).