# Operators panel missing

Tags: operator, panel

I wanted to make my very first blender donut yesterday. I have ver 2 82.7 When I add the torus it pulls up a floating menu where i can amend size and segments. When I click anywhere else this Add torus floating panel disappears - how can I get it back? I tried the edit - adjust last operation  but that only works if I haven't done anything inbetween like moving the object, otherwise it will just pull up the the last action obviously. I would like to have this Add Torus panel visible at all times so i can amend segments at any point of making this project.

[image: screenshot attached]

Comment: Hi Zsuzsanna, that's a limitation unfortunately. Does this answer your question? [How to adjust operator settings after leaving the settings panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2295/how-to-adjust-operator-settings-after-leaving-the-settings-panel)